# List list = new ArrayList()と宣言するのはやめたほうがいいのではないか

Tags: java

プログラミング入門などではよく`ArrayList list = new ArrayList()`ではなく`List list = new ArrayList()`と書きましょうという記述がありますが、本当にこれは優れた書き方なのでしょうか？
例えば[英語のstackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329311/reason-for-list-list-new-arraylist)では変化によく対応するために`List list = new ArrayList()`という書き方がいいとされています。もしArrayListではなくLinkedListにした方がいい場合になったら`new ArrayList()`の部分だけ書き変えればいい、と。

しかし本当にそうでしょうか。[軽い気持ちでLinkedListを使ったら休出する羽目になった話 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/neko_machi/items/d620c4a8958e74df3550)のように、以下のコードのようなランダムアクセスが多発するコードを書いていた場合、

```
for (int i = 0; i*2 < data.size(); i++) {
    MyClass record = data.get(i*2);
}
```

`List list = new ArrayList()`という記述を見て後任者が「なるほどこのコードではListであれば何でもいいんだな。じゃあちょっと挿入処理したい所があるからLinkedListに変えよう」となったら記事にあるように激遅コードになってしまいます。

Listに限らず、インターフェイスによる宣言は「そのインターフェイスで実装されるメソッドはすべて同様の動作をする」ことが保証されない限り使うべきではないのではないでしょうか。

追記：英語版でも質問してみました https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64868813/is-list-list-new-arraylist-really-desirable-from-arraylist-list-new-arr

Comment: Upvoteが多いので多くの人の関心が高そうですが、この記事自身は「意見の表明と議論の喚起」に見えます。外野からは [どのような質問は避けるべきですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) の「自分が直面している実際の問題に基づいて、実用的で回答可能な質問のみをしてください。」とか「質問の動機が「\_\_に関する議論に参加したい」である場合は、ここで質問しないでください。」に該当している感じなので、回答やコメントの方向性も含めて考え直してもらった方が良いと思われます。

Answer (score 4):

`List`型(インタフェース)より具象型で表す方が妥当な状況もあるかとは思いますが、質問文リンク先[Qiitaの事例](https://qiita.com/neko_machi/items/d620c4a8958e74df3550)、及び質問文中の事例とも、特にそういった状況には当てはまらない(つまり`List`を用いるのが妥当)かと思います。

---

インタフェースに対しては**利用者**と**提供者**(実装者)という2つの立場があり、Qiitaの記事は利用者の、質問文のものは提供者の立場の事例です(※質問文の事例はどちらとも取れるので誤解しているかもしれません)。

そして具象型でなく`List`型として提供するのは、**利用者**が実装を意識せずに済むのが利点であり、**提供者**に対する利点ではないです。つまり、質問文の事例では

> 「なるほどこのコードではListであれば何でもいいんだな。じゃあちょっと挿入処理したい所があるからLinkedListに変えよう」

という考え方が誤りであり、提供者は`List`かどうかに関わらず想定される利用方法に対して適切な実装を提供する必要があります。

他方、Qiitaの事例は、`List`の利用方法の誤りだと言えるかと思います。

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html

> 一部の実装(LinkedListクラスなど)では、これらのオペレーションの実行にはインデックス値に比例した時間がかかる場合があります。 このため、呼出し側がこうした実装について知らない場合は、リストにインデックスを付けるよりも、リスト内の要素を反復してください。

---

> インターフェイスによる宣言は「そのインターフェイスで実装されるメソッドはすべて同様の動作をする」ことが保証されない限り使うべきではない

(この点について留意すべき者は利用者でなく提供者かと考えますが、この点はひとまず置いておいて)
今回の事例で言うと、`List`はインデクスによるアクセスの計算量について何か規定/保証しているわけではありません。
むしろ、実装によって計算量が異なることを示唆しており、実際にそうなっている、ということです。

Answer (score 1):

java でこの問題がどう取り扱われているかというと、[RandomAccess interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/7/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html)が提供されていて、少なくとも `instanceof` で与えられた List を実装しているオブジェクトが random access 可能かを判定できるようになっている様子です。

ポイントは、具体的な実装クラスだと変更可能性に欠けるが、`List` だとゆるすぎるのが問題だと思っており、もしランダムアクセス機能がクリティカルな場合には、その箇所で runtime チェックを行って、 RandomAccess の instance じゃなかったら例外を発生させる、みたいな実装がありえるかな、と思いました。

Java なので、何かしらのテストは実装していると思われるので、そこで例えば `LinkedList` を与えた場合には例外が発生して test が fail するようにすれば、他の実装者はそこで気付けるようになるのではないかな、と思います。

Comment: 対応方法としてはわかるのですが、だとすると`List list = new ArrayList()`と書きましょうという言説にはすべて「もしランダムアクセスが存在する場合LinkedListだと激遅になるのでinstanceofでランダムアクセス可能かチェックするコードを入れるかテストに大量件数を処理する場合短時間で処理が終わるかチェックするテストを入れましょう」という注釈が必要になり初学者（中級者でも？）は混乱してしまうと思います。それくらいなら`ArrayList list = new ArrayList()`と書くようにして、一歩上のテクニックとして「同様の処理をする似たようなクラスをいくつか作る場合はインターフェイスで実装&宣言してみよう」とした方がいいと思います。

Comment: どのように教育するか、はひとまずこの ja.stackoverflow では off topic ぎみ、という前提のもと、自分の回答は技術的な意味での「`List list = new ArrayList()`の是非」について回答してみた次第です。

Answer (score 1):

私も大体同じような考えを持っており「Javaが標準で持っているクラスのインスタンスは、インタフェース名で受けない」方が良いと考えています。
コレクションに関して言えば、インタフェース名で受けるのはメソッドの引数くらいかなと思います。

Answer (score 1):

設計としてArrayListの機能を要求されるのであればArrayListにするべきだと思いますし、汎用的なメソッド的なものを想定しているのであればListにすればよいのではないのでしょうか。
一概にこうすべき、と断じれるものではないと思います。
設計には前提が必要であり、特に前提を定めないのであれば、可能な限り抽象化しておくのが理想ではないかなと個人的に思います。